# Using regex to verify an input has at least 2 letters, with special and normal characters allowed

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression which should have at least 2 letters.
Total length should be between 6 & 50 characters and can as well include these special characters - _ . @

I came up with this line but it still accepts when I have in the input 1 letter and one special character with a minimum of 6 characters in total.
Where there should be 2 letters minimum for the input to be valid.

```
^(?=(?:\d*\D){2})[a-zA-Z0-9-_@\\.]{6,50}$
```

I expect it to be valid when I give for example : a12@45b 
And expect to be invalid when I give for example : a1234@  (this output gives me valid with expression I have now)

Comment: `\D` matches any non-digit char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching not a digit `\D` does not guarantee a character a-z.

You could update the positive lookahead to assert 2 times not a-zA-Z and then a-zA-Z. Note that you don't have to escape the dot in the character class.

```
^(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[A-Za-z]){2})[a-zA-Z0-9-_@.]{6,50}$
```

Or as suggested in the comment by [@Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637853/thomas)  make the pattern case insensitive and use only a-z:

```
^(?i)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})[a-z0-9-_@.]{6,50}$
```

Comment: Making the query case-insensitive could increase readibility: `^(?i)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})[a-z0-9-_@.]{6,50}$`

Comment: Just came up with this expression and passed as well: `^(?=(([0-9-.@]*)([a-zA-Z]{1,})([0-9-.@]*)([a-zA-Z]{1,})([0-9-.@]*)))[a-zA-Z0-9-@.]{6,50}$`

Comment: @ExileNoir That is also possible, but you have to add matching the underscore as it is currently missing from the pattern and you don't need all the capturing groups if you want a match only. You could also shorten the assertion because the last part is not mandatory for the assertion to succeed. You might update it to `^(?=(?:[0-9-.@_]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9-.@_]*[a-zA-Z]))[a-zA-Z0-9-@._]{6,50}$`